# Pegar último ID ou data inserida em uma tabela do Mysql

Tags: sql, select

Tenho um historico de conversas que ficam registrados na tabela sql "conversa" e quero pegar quem foi a ultima pessoa que inseriu uma mensagem na conversa para saber se foi o usuario que escreveu por ultimo ou se foi o admin (id 28).

Tem alguma forma de fazer um SELECT com uma regra para saber qual a ultima data ou úlitmo id?

```
id|idusuario|idconversa|  mensagem  |data
1 | 700     |    2     | mensagem 1 |2018-05-24 10:20:21
2 | 28      |    2     | mensagem 2 |2018-05-24 10:30:21
```

Montei o seguinte:

```
SELECT idusuario
FROM conversa
GROUP BY idconversa
```

Aí quando retornar o ultimo id que inseriu a conversa vou fazer um if para dizer se foi o admin ou o usuario (essa parte já está ok);

Comment: Tá fazendo com PHP?

Comment: Isso, to fazendo em PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ideia é que você traga tudo de uma vez? O código abaixo traz a data mais atual, agrupando pelo id da conversa e do usuário:

```
SELECT idconversa, idusuario, max(data)
FROM conversa 
GROUP BY idconversa, idusuario
```

Caso queira apenas de uma conversa específica, você não precisaria retornar o `idconversa` nem agrupar por esse campo, ficando assim:

```
SELECT idusuario
FROM conversa 
WHERE idconversa = 2 --aqui ficaria o parâmetro de entrada (id da conversa pesquisada)
ORDER BY data desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: isso, a ideia é trazer todas as conversas agrupadas, com a data e idusuario da ultima linha adicionada. Fiz desse jeito, mas ele está trazendo a primeira linha e não a ultima... :/

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo dá uma sacada se resolveu, alterei a resposta

Comment: Boa! deu certo, o max(data) resolveu, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Voce vai ordernar de forma decrescente.

```
SELECT idusuario
FROM conversa
GROUP BY idconversa
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: fiz isso, mas ele trouxe o id 1, e não o ultimo

Answer (score 0):

Os SQLs abaixo foram feitos para Oracle, mas podem ser adaptados para MySQ.

--tabela preenchida

**select id, idusuario, idconversa, mensagem, to_char(data, 'dd/mm/yyy hh24:mi:ss') from tb_conversa;**

```
    ID  IDUSUARIO IDCONVERSA MENSAGEM             TO_CHAR(DATA,'DD/M
```

---

```
     1        700          2 m1                   24/05/018 10:49:51
     2         28          2 m2                   24/05/018 14:50:25
     3         30          2 m3                   24/05/018 12:50:51
     4          1          1 m4                   24/05/018 12:51:54
     5        700          1 m5                   24/05/018 12:52:11
     6         28          1 m6                   24/05/018 14:52:28
```

--pegando as datas máximas por conversa

**select idconversa, max(to_char(data, 'dd/mm/yyy hh24:mi:ss')) data_max
from tb_conversa
group by idconversa;**

IDCONVERSA DATA_MAX

---

```
     1 24/05/018 14:52:28
     2 24/05/018 14:50:25
```

--trazendo as linhas que atende a data máxima, por conversa

**select t1.*
from tb_conversa t1,
(
select idconversa, max(to_char(data, 'dd/mm/yyy hh24:mi:ss')) data_max
from tb_conversa
group by idconversa
) t2
where t1.idconversa = t2.idconversa and to_char(t1.data, 'dd/mm/yyy hh24:mi:ss') like t2.data_max;**

```
    ID  IDUSUARIO IDCONVERSA MENSAGEM             DATA
```

---

```
     6         28          1 m6                   24/05/18
     2         28          2 m2                   24/05/18
```

Desculpa a formatação, sou novo no StackOverFlow.